# Converting Word .doc file to a Flash Swf file

Tags: conversion, microsoft-word, swf

I am looking for a way to convert .doc files (Microsoft word) to swf.
At the moment I am copy pasting each page from Word to an .fla(in a Flash authoring tool) and then publishing  it as an swf.
Actually I would want to convert each page or selection from my .doc file to swf's ...
Do you'll have any suggestions?

EDIT: Well actually the output swf generated should have a comparable size to the one that is generated from copy pasting word page to fla and then publishing it..I think, Most of the softwares generate bloated swf...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Free alternative with two step process

- use [PDF Creator](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfcreator/) to print doc file to pdf
- use [SWF tools](http://www.swftools.org/) to convert pdf to swf

> SWFTools is a collection of utilities for working with Adobe Flash files (SWF files). The tool collection includes programs for reading SWF files, combining them, and creating them from other content (like images, sound files, videos or sourcecode).

Comment: Nice suggestion! Lemme check on the output size of the .swf thats the most important criteria... will get back to you!

Answer (score 4):

The quickest tool (but not free) that I can think of is [Adobe Flash Paper](http://www.adobe.com/products/flashpaper/), it basically installs a virtual printer and it can save output as SWF.

Alternatively, you can use an online service such as [Scribd](http://www.scribd.com/), which does something similar but I believe, like Youtube, they host all the content.

Comment: Again the swf size of Adobe Flash Paper is much larger than expected ....

Comment: What is the actual size problem? How much are we talking about? You can always look in options and reduce quality.

Answer (score 1):

Found this commercial product : [SWF Printer](http://www.what-means.com/converters/show/678).

> Virtual printer converting printed
>   documents into flash (SWF) with
>   navigation support. Can be used from
>   every program that supports printing
>   (incl. PDF, DOC, XLS). "Silent"
>   automation mode is supported (for both
>   end-users and software developers who
>   want to incorporate SWF printer into
>   their applications or web-server
>   applications).

Comment: Seems to be good, but will have to buy and then check comparative file sizes of swf... any FOSS solution?

Comment: Didn't find one, but doesn't mean it doesn't exist. If you google for "swf printer", I'm sure you can find some shareware downloads to ensure that your money is well spent.

Answer (score 1):

A version similiar al flash paper  es 2 es Print to Flash http://print2flash.com/

Answer (score 0):

Well I actually found [this](http://www.bytescout.com/swfprinter_converting_documents_into_swf_flash_movie_tutorial.html) free version it says SWF Printer (Pro) don't know whether its related to the option the Harry suggested however this one seems to be free!
But still I'm not happy with the size results may work for you though...