# Auto .doc file to .swf conversion

Tags: conversion, automation, microsoft-word, swf

Well I had posted a question [here](https://superuser.com/questions/47862/converting-word-doc-file-to-a-flash-swf-file) but I don't think that any existing software solutions exist that would give me the output swf size that I am looking for so I would like to go for my older method but automate it with your help :)

Now I want to execute the following steps:

- Break/split the word(.doc) file into
  small chunks.
- Taking one chunk at a time I will
  copy the matter(text and sometimes
  images) onto the clipboard.
- Paste the matter into the Flash
  authoring tool and somehow publish to
  swf.

Phew! so how do I execute the above automatically?...
Alternatively if you have better solutions its more than welcome!!

Comment: Why does it need to be a swf? A pdf won't due?

Comment: @MarkM: No, specifically need it to be a swf...

Comment: More of a programming thing - belongs on StackOverflow

Comment: @ ChrisF: I ain't need to program, I believe there may be some tools like Robotask or the likes which will help me accomplish this...

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question directly first: you might be able to automate your process using a script written in vbscript or jscript under the Windows Scripting Host, by creating scripts that start the relevant applications and contol them via SendKeys. See some examples [here](http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/ezine/ezine26.htm), [here](http://www.pctools.com/guides/scripting/detail/149/?act=reference), and many other places (search for "vbscript sendkeys" or similar in `<insert search engine name here>`). Unfortunately the comments on the Microsoft documentation for sendkeys ([found here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8c6yea83(VS.85).aspx)) suggest that this will not work under Vista.

---

What is your particular need to have the documents in SWF format? The answer to that might net you some suggestions of other ways to achieve your goal if it turns out the software you are currently looking for does not exist.

If you are wanting to publish documents so they can be read by web users who may not have either the relevant word processor or other document reader (such as Acrobat Reader for which you could convert the documents to PDF instead), then you might be able to use an embedded instance of Google's document viewer. This works without any extra client applications or plugins (you just need Javascript turned on in your browser) though you will still need to convert the documents to PDF format, as it doesn't support any word processor formats directly, and make the PDF available online somewhere. [See this page for an example](http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2009/09/embeddable-google-document-viewer.html).

One further point that may help get relevant answers: can you describe the content of the documents in question? Are they all text, a few graphics, or very graphical? A few pages each or hundreds? What is the initial size of the documents (before conversion) and the resulting sizes that are too large?

Comment: I need swf output to publish them on the web. Contents are text with sparse graphics...

Comment: The embedded Google document viewer may well be suitable in that case. Also, is there any reason why you have chosen a format other than HTML (+CSS) for publishing the documents? Trying to protect the content from copy+paste perhaps? (which would preclude the HTML or Google docs options, but you should be aware that anyone determined to get your text out of the SWFs would probably be able to do so with minimal effort).

Comment: No copy protection is not an issue here its just that I would like to stick to swfs here as the customers requires them in that format..

Comment: Ah, the entrenched customer. I know a few of them. No logical or practical alternatives will sway their minds when they have decided beyond all doubt that their first choice is the right one!

Answer (score -1):

Try this link. It will work:

http://print2flash.com/download.php

I have personally tried this.

Comment: What is it? Please enter some detail about the link you've provided.